# What is the next number of this sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, matrices

Consider the sequence $ (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of positive integers whose first few entries are

> $ 2 ~~ 6 ~~ 20 ~~ 70 ~~ 252 ~~ \ldots $

Now, consider the infinite matrix

> \begin{equation}
> \left[
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & \cdots \\
> 1      & 2      & 3      & 4      & 5      & 6      & \cdots \\
> 1      & 3      & 6      & 10     & 15     & 21     & \cdots \\
> 1      & 4      & 10     & 20     & 35     & 56     & \cdots \\
> 1      & 5      & 15     & 35     & 70     & 126    & \cdots \\
> 1      & 6      & 21     & 56     & 126    & 252    & \cdots \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
> \end{array} \right].
> \end{equation}

- The $ (i,j) $-entry of this matrix indicates the number of ways of traveling from the $ (1,1) $-entry to the $ (i,j) $-entry of an $ (n \times n) $-matrix by only moving either right or down.
- The sequence $ (a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is formed from the diagonal elements of this matrix, starting from the $ (2,2) $-entry.

> **Question:** How does one generate the $ n $-th entry of the sequence without referring to the matrix above? Is there a generating function for the sequence?

Comment: [**Central binomial coefficient**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), also see [**Central binomial coefficients**](http://oeis.org/A000984)

Comment: The number of moves to the right and the number of moves down must both equal $n-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the matrix $a(i,j) = \dbinom{i+j}i$. You are interested in the diagonal elements i.e. $$a(n,n) = \dbinom{n+n}n = \dbinom{2n}n$$

Answer (score 2):

The formula is
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad a_{n} = \binom{2n}{n}.
$$
Notice that if you rotate the infinite square matrix $ 45^{\circ} $ clockwise, you will obtain Pascal's Triangle. This shows, heuristically, that the sequence is made up of the central binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Marvis and Haskell Curry have given you the closed formula.

You also asked for the generating function, which is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}.$$